# Fill and submit html form

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying / wanting to write a Python script (2.7) that goes to a form on a website (with the name `"form1"`) and fills in the first input-field in said form with the word `hello`, the second input-field with the word `Ronald`, and the third field with `ronaldG54@gmail.com`

Can anyone help me code or give me any tips or pointers on how to do this ?

Answer (score 19):

Aside from Mechanize and Selenium David has mentioned, it can also be achieved with [`Requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) and [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

To be more clear, use `Requests` to send request to and retrieve responses from server, and use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the response html to know what parameters to send to the server.

Here is an example script I wrote that uses both `Requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to submit username and password to login to wikipedia:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def get_login_token(raw_resp):
    soup = bs(raw_resp.text, 'lxml')
    token = [n['value'] for n in soup.find_all('input')
             if n['name'] == 'wpLoginToken']
    return token[0]

payload = {
    'wpName': 'my_username',
    'wpPassword': 'my_password',
    'wpLoginAttempt': 'Log in',
    #'wpLoginToken': '',
    }

with requests.session() as s:
    resp = s.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin')
    payload['wpLoginToken'] = get_login_token(resp)

    response_post = s.post('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&action=submitlogin&type=login',
                           data=payload)
    response = s.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Watchlist')
```

---

Update:

For your specific case, here is the working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def get_session_id(raw_resp):
    soup = bs(raw_resp.text, 'lxml')
    token = soup.find_all('input', {'name':'survey_session_id'})[0]['value']
    return token

payload = {
    'f213054909': 'o213118718',  # 21st checkbox
    'f213054910': 'Ronald',  # first input-field
    'f213054911': 'ronaldG54@gmail.com',
    }

url = r'https://app.e2ma.net/app2/survey/39047/213008231/f2e46b57c8/?v=a'

with requests.session() as s:
    resp = s.get(url)
    payload['survey_session_id'] = get_session_id(resp)
    response_post = s.post(url, data=payload)
    print response_post.text
```

Comment: Ah, okay. I can kind of see how this works, but I am confused on how to do some things still.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to achieve the following instance of filling a form, that way I can learn how to fill out the form I am trying to?



The form is located at https://app.e2ma.net/app2/survey/39047/213008231/f2e46b57c8/?v=a

Comment: I am trying to fill the form with the id of " survey_form ".


Then I want to tick the 21st check-box, which has an id of " option_213118718 ".


Second, I want to fill the first input-field, with an id of " field_213054910_input " and a name of " f213054910 ", with the text ' Ronald '.

Comment: and the next input-field with an id of ' field_213054911_input ' and name of ' f213054911 '. I want to fill that with the text ' ronaldG54@gmail.com ' and then submit the form.



I would really appreciate any and all help in solving this.

Comment: @IrfanM I've updated with the working code. Bare in mind that it's still worth learning `Mechanize` and `Selenium` too.

Comment: I'm getting an error: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) and [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). Both are excellent pieces of software that would allow you to automate filling and submitting a form, among other browser tasks.

Comment: I've heard of Mechanize before, but I am confused on how to do what I am trying to accomplish. More specifically actually filling out the form with those lines.

Is there any way you could give or show me some basic code to start off from?

Comment: Mechanize comes with tons of example scripts. There's a whole [section devoted to forms](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html) that should help you get started.