# How to auto fill login values on html5 form through a python script?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, forms, authentication

I am trying to make a script that auto fills the HTML5 form values (Name and Password). I don't know how to insert the values.

On other sites I can't find a good explanation about how to do it.

Login site: [https://ncod22.n-able.com/](https://ncod22.n-able.com)

*username = TestName 

password = TestPwd 

(These aren't working)*

Pyton code (so far):

```
import webbrowser, sys
webbrowser.open('https://ncod22.n-able.com/')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill and submit html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756443/fill-and-submit-html-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [mechanize](https://pypi.org/project/mechanize/):

```
import mechanize
url="https://ncod22.n-able.com/"
pg=mechanize.Browser()
pg.set_handle_robots(False)
r=pg.open(url)   #open page
pg.select_form(nr=0)   #select form number
pg.form["username"]="TestName"   #<input> name
pg.form["password"]="TestPwd"   #<input name="password">
pg.method="POST"   #form method
r=pg.submit()   #submitting form
#print(r.read())    to see Page source
```