# How to change checkbox value with python

Tags: python, python-requests

Im very new to python and web scraping etc but Im trying to learn while I read but Im stuck now. I have managed to use python and BeautifulSoup to grab a kinda web form from a page where theres alot of checkboxes. What Im trying to do is change some of these checkboxes from checked to unchecked or the other way around. But dont know where to really go from here.

The output from a checkbox thats checked looks like this:

```
    <div class="checkbox">
     <label>
      <input checked="checked" name="Permissions" type="checkbox" value="SeeDetailedInformation"/>
     </label>
    </div>
```

The output from a checkbox thats not checked looks like this:

```
    <div class="checkbox">
     <label>
      <input name="Permissions" type="checkbox" value="AdjustCounters"/>
     </label>
    </div>
```

Question is how do I change the checkbox to not beeing check or checked if thats what I want using requests.post or any other good method of changing this.

Any help with either code I can try or pointers to where I should read up on this is much appriciated. I have read abit about selenium and webdriver but dont think this will do it for me as I have 500+ pages/forms on different urls to change. (Going from url to url isnt a problem, I just need some input on have to change the checkbox)

Comment: The checkbox doesn't exist, only a description of it. If you want to create a query, don't include the parameter if it should be unchecked, or include it if it should be checked, e.g. `Permissions=AdjustCounters`

Comment: @PeterWood You have an example of how that query could be written? Im all new to this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12757144/1084416

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and its use as a driver for your browser. Beautifulsoup is great for parsing documents, and I'm not familiar with it's usage in form completion, but selenium can certainly do what you're looking for. I would check out this snippet of code too:

```
checkboxes = webdriver.find_elements_by_class('checkbox')
for i in range(len(checkboxes)):
    checkbox = checkboxes[i]
    if ((values[i] and not checkbox.is_selected()) or (not values[i] and checkbox.is_selected())):
        checkbox.click()
```

where *values* is a list of booleans representing whether each checkbox should be selected or not.