# Web scraper error in Python - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Currently building a web scraper using beautifulsoap, in order to get a list of body shop location by submitting ZIP code. ([Website](https://owners.honda.com/collision/profirstbodyshop/))

When I specified an id of an element ("dl-zipcode") and tried to see if it works, it keeps saying an error below:

> search_box = soup.find_element_by_id("dl-zipcode")
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

I've searched for an answer for hours, and decided to ask since I couldn't find a solution.

Below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://owners.honda.com/collision/profirstbodyshop/'
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


myList = [28012, 28011]

results = []

for i in myList:
    search_box = soup.find_element_by_id("dl-zipcode")
    search_box.send_keys(i)
    search_box.submit()
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide details of the error such as which line is throwing the error...generally 'NoneType'  means the object returned is NULL. Also I could not find a `find_element_by_id` function in BS4 documentation...make sure it exists

Comment: It was an error from a line "search_box = soup.find_element_by_id("dl-zipcode")"

Answer (score 0):

Changing your parser to lxml should fix your issue, also, you should pass .text instead of .content.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
```

If you want to see the difference procued by html.parser and lxml check out `diagnose():` https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#diagnose

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it still gave me the same error ("TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable") . I tried lxml, xml, lxml-xml, and html5lib; but nothing worked :(

Comment: Updated my answer, I actually think it's because you're using .content and not .text

Comment: Thank you I just did find(id="dl-zipcode") and it worked; however, I keep getting the same "NoneType" object error on the next line of code :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the input for the table and submit the request, in this case it should be this line you look for:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="You must enter a valid zip code." data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$" data-val-required="The Zip field is required." id="from-zip" name="Zip" type="text" value="" />
```

And then submit based on that. I hope that helps. An example is here:
 [Fill and submit html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756443/fill-and-submit-html-form)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did (1st line)  search_box = soup.find(id="from-zip")
      (2nd line)   search_box.send_keys(i) 
It worked for the first line, but it still gave me the same NoneType error on the second line :(