# How could i fill out a newsletter signup promt with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to fill out an email form on any newsletter site with python. I don't want to use anything that spawns a browser window, i want it all in one script. Thanks in advance.

I tried using the requests module but just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill and submit html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756443/fill-and-submit-html-form)